# Uploading images along with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, image-uploading

I'm working on a Google App Engine project.

My app is working and looking correct locally, but when I try to upload images in an image directory, they're not being displayed at appspot.

As a little troubleshoot, I put a HTML page in "/images/page2.html" and I can load that page at the appspot, but my pages don't display my images. So, it's not a problem with my path.

As another sanity check, I'm also uploading a style sheet directory with .css code in it, and that's being read properly.

I have a suspicion that the problem lies in my app.yaml file.

Any ideas?

I don't want to paste all the code here, but here are some of the key lines. The first two work fine. The third does not work:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
<a href="/images/Page2.html">Page 2</a>
<img src="/images/img.gif">
```

This is my app.yaml file

```
application: myApp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Mind to share how you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You have to configure app.yaml for static content such as images and css files

Example:

```
 url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
```

For more info check out:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/configuringanapp.html

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet your problem is that you're using Windows.

If that's the case, I believe you need a preceding slash for your static_dir value.

Comment: Now that's interesting -- I just got into work, and now I want to go home to try this. 

I'll check back (but it might be monday) with an update. 

BTW, is there documentation to what you're talking about that I might have overlooked somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Java version of App engine, and I faced a similar issues with the server not able to serve static images.

What worked ultimately was to change the AppEngine config file "appengine-web.xml" in my case to contain

```xml
<static-files>
    <include path="**.*"/>
    <include path="/images/**.*" />
</static-files>
```

My images are in the /images directory and HTML and CSS are in . directory  which is at the WEB-INF level

Answer (score 0):

@jamtoday The preceding slash didn't make a difference, but it did get me started figuring out what each app needs to be told what about my directory structure.

So, I have nothing very conclusive to add, but I wanted to follow up, because I got it working, but I didn't explore all the issues after I got it working.

One change that helped was to stop working from a HwlloWorld/src/ directory and start working in the HelloWorld/ directory. It seems like the dev_appserver picked up all the dependencies, but the remote server didn't. Essentially, the relative path of my local links didn't match the relative path of the links after uploading.

I also realized that the dev-appserver relies on the .yaml file, as well as the appcfg script. That is. . .if you add a directory to your project, and then try to link to files in that directory, you need to add the directory to the .yaml file, and then restart the dev-appserver to pick up on this.

So, there are probably ways to handle what I was originally trying to do if you give the .yaml file the right info, but changing to a different directory structure locally handled it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="/images/img.gif">
```

this line  can't show you the image.
Try this one:

1-Create a class to handle "image request"

```py
class GetImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
       self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpg'
       self.response.out.write(image_object)
```

2-In your page.html:

```html
<img src="/image"
```

3-At the main function in your code.py:

```py
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(('/image', GetImage), debug=True)
```

have fun

Comment: Is your "2" written entirely or did it get cut off? 

It seems like you're trying to make a general GetImage class, but where do you tell it the actual image? What if I want to display "image1.jpg" in one place, and "image2.jpg" in the other. What are the html calls?